# Tensor中からマッチする要素のindexの返し方について

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow初心者です。
コードの書き方が全くわからなくて困っています。
もし良ければ教えて頂きたいです。

質問なんですけれど、
入力データは縦20横20の配列で、
1行に入る要素は'1'が1個、残りは'0'です。
それが20列あります。

答えは縦1横20の配列で、
これも要素は'1'が1個、'0'が19個です。

【例】5*5の場合

```
1　0　0　0　0
0　1　0　0　0
0　1　0　0　0　　→　　0　1　0　0　0
0　0　1　0　0
0　0　0　0　1
　入力データ　　　　　　答えデータ
```

入力データから、任意の'1'を選んで、
答えと一致させるプログラムを作りたいです。
例の場合だと、左から2番目を選んでほしいです。
（2行目か3行目かは問わない）

TensorflowのチュートリアルのMNISTをそのまま
入力データを上記のに替えて試しましたが
学習の正答率があがりませんでした。
私がやりたいのにはフィルターなどはいらないと
分かったものの、どうコードを書いて良いのか
全く分からない状態です。

教えてください、お願いします。

Comment: 質問内容の「(5,5)のtensor中から、一致する要素のindexを返す」という件については解決したとの認識ですのでクローズお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tf.argmax()を使うことでそのtensorlの最大値が入っているindexを得ることができます。(例の答えの場合1が得られます)

tf.equal()を使うことで要素が一致するindexにTrueが入ったtensorを得ることが出来ます。

tf.where()にてTrueとなるindexの位置を得ることが出来ます。

例の場合入力データをx
答えデータをy
とすると
tf.equal(tf.argmax(x,1),tf.argmax(y,0))
とすることで
array([False,  True,  True, False, False]
というtensorが得ることが出来。

tf.where(tf.equal(tf.argmax(x,1),tf.argmax(y,0)))
とすることで
array([1],[2])
が得ることが出来ます。

---

追記：
質問者様の「配列」を勝手にtensorであると思って回答しましたが、
np.array等で生成された普通の配列のことを指していましたでしょうか。
であればそれぞれ
np.where
np.equal
np.argmax
に置き換えることで同様の処理が可能です。

Comment: 分かりやすく教えて頂いてありがとうございます。  
それをどのようにプログラムにしたらいいのか分からないのです…  
MNISTのプログラムそのまま使っているので、  
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])  
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])  
  
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)  
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)  
 
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])  
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])  
 
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)  
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)  

このようになっているのですが、  
これをどう変えていいかわからないです。  
教えて頂けると嬉しいです。

Comment: 本題からかなりそれてしまうのですが、tensorflowのCNN MNISTのネットワークを形成した場合、算出されるtensorは(-1,10)の形になります。(要素10のtensorがデータ個数分)。ですので評価の段階では(5,5)の形ではありませんので元々のご質問の方法とは形が異なるものとなります。また、入力データと答えの関係ですが、「どの入力データも入力データの2番目か3番目に答えが出現する」であれば学習を重ねることで正答率があがっていくかと思いますが、「入力データのどこかに答えのtensorが含まれる」だとMNISTのネットワークでは正当率は上がらないかと思います。乱暴な言い方をするとニューラルネットワーくは法則をみつける仕組みとなりますので、ご提示の問題設定ですと入力に対する答えの法則がないように思えます。(私が理解できていないだけで、「こういう入力の時は答えはこうだ」がありましたらご教示お願いします。)

Comment: MNISTのコードを見直してみましたが(5,5)は入力の大きさではなくフィルタ(重み)の大きさではないでしょうか？入力は(28,28)かと思います。質問者様で入力の大きさを変更為されたのかもしれませんが、であればフルコードを見てみたいところです。いずれにせよ元々の質問からはかなりそれてきてしまっているので別エントリにてご質問されてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32003/tensorflow%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6-%E5%88%9D%E5%BF%83%E8%80%85%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-%E2%91%A1  
見て頂けると嬉しいです